# Statistical test for pseudo replicates

Tags: anova, sample-size

I film the take-off of flies. I have two sets of data. The first set are normal controls. And the second set of flies are physically perturbed. I wish to see the difference in the take of behaviour of these two sets of flies.

Now, the way I film these flies is that I release a bunch of them together and I take videos. I had 3 filming session for controls. And I have 10 videos from these three filming sessions. Since I did not mark the flies, I have no way knowing how many distinct flies I can get from each session. So thus I have 10 videos from 3 days or 10 flights from n=3 flies.

The process is similar for perturbed flies as well. 10 flights from n=3 flies.

I clearly cannot say n=10 flies. That will be a pseudo replication.

So how do I compare these two data sets?

Can I assume that the 10 observations in these datasets are mutually independent, even though some observations come from the same fly? And the probably run some kind of ANOVA.

Or should I just dump this dataset and collect n=10 flights for n=10 flies?